# BottomSheet style after using MaterialComponents Theme

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles, bottom-sheet, material-components-android

Recently I switched to using `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0` for app theme.

In addition to set `colorPrimary`,`colorPrimaryDark` and `colorAccent` and using `MaterialButton` with `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` style, buttons in activity/fragment and bottomSheetFragment are different in colors!

in Activity/Fragment is OK. but in BottomSheet has a different color (green).

[image]

Comment: What are the defined colors? How is your theme defined? What's the actual output? What's the expected output?

Comment: added screenshot to answering your questions. @EugenPechanec

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define a new style for BottomSheetDialogFragment:

```
 <style name="MyBottomSheetStyle" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
 </style>
```

You can apply it via app theme by setting it as `bottomSheetDialogTheme` in main app style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...

    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/MyBottomSheetStyle</item>
</style>
```

or override `getTheme()` of in your bottom-sheet class.

```
override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.MyBottomSheetStyle
```

If you choose second one, It's better to use a base class and implement `getTheme()` on it.

Comment: after applying custom bottom sheet style, it looks weird. After adding color attribtues, it's working good.

Comment: @KhayLeang I can't access to original screenshot after years. but I improved my answer.